# PhotoViewAttacher clears imageView bounds and zoom level

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I'm using [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library for the implementation of a zooming `Android` `ImageView`. The zooming works fine.

I'm setting an image with `low-quality` in `ImageView` and then start to download the new image with `hight-quality` which will replace the `low-quality` image.

If the user zooms in the `low-quality` image - the `high-quality` image replaces the existing image and the zoom level clears :(

How can I save the zoom level after loading the `high-quality` image?

I've tried to get the image `Matrix` from `PhotoViewAttacher` in `low-quality` and set it to the `high-quality image`, but it doesn't work - the image zoom level and bounds aren't the same as they were before. The `high-quality` image replaced the `low-quality` image in `ImageView`.

```
    Matrix matrix;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    ...

    PhotoViewAttacher  mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
    // save the matrix before any modifications
    matrix = mAttacher.getDisplayMatrix(); 
    mAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(new OnMatrixChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {
            // update the matrix
            matrix = mAttacher.getDisplayMatrix(); 
        }
    });

    imageProvider.load(getActivity(), imageView, imageUrl, progressBarView, imageConfig, new ImageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ImageView imageView) {
            // update image in ImageView
            // probably the problem is in this .update() call
            // but I don't get what's the exact problem
            mAttacher.update();
            // restore high-quality image matrix
            mAttacher.setDisplayMatrix(matrix);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ImageView imageView) {

        }
    });
```

**Edit:** Images have different dimensions.

Comment: I've never used this library, but as a workaround it seems you can call `mAttacher.setZoomable(false)` to disable zoom capabilities when you display the low-quality image, and then enable it once the high-quality is shown.

Comment: it's a good solution, and it will work. But I have to provide zoom capabilities to the user, it's a requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code of [PhotoViewAttacher.java](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/PhotoViewAttacher.java) - it seems that calling `update()` does two things:

1. Ensure the scale type for `ImageView` is set to `ScaleType.MATRIX`.
2. Invalidate the current matrix and recalculate it according to the dimensions of the new `Drawable`.

So, assuming your first and second image both have exactly the same dimensions, you can just skip the `update()` call, which should retain the current zoom and pan values.

Comment: Images have different dimensions :( yes, `update()` does it. I have to transform somehow low-quality image matrix to high-quality image matrix and save proportions.